# cleaning up super gross arrow head anti-pattern in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm looking to get rid of bad habits early and start writing clean and efficient code. I am working on a console application that references an API and i have a series of deeply nested 'if's (at points up to 10 levels deep!).

```
commonLogic forQuote = new commonLogic();

if (countryRes == CountryDes)
{
    //staying in country
    try2:
    //display reasons for travel
    Console.WriteLine("What Best Describes Your Reason For Traveling?");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine("1. United States Resident traveling Inside the U.S.");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Visiting United States For Business or Pleasure.");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Immigrating to The Unites States.");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Student, Faculty Member or Scholar With a J-1, F-1, H-3, M-1, or Q-1 Visa.");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    var x = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();

    if (x == "1")
    {
        //US resident
        //first print
        forQuote.gatherUserData();
    }
    else if (x == "2")
    {
        try3:
        //visiting the US
        Console.WriteLine("What Type of Coverage Do You Need?");
        Console.WriteLine(" "); 
        Console.WriteLine("1. Medical voerage");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Trip Cancellation");
        var r = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.Clear();

        if (r == "1")
        {
            //medical coverage
            Console.WriteLine("What Type of Medical Coverage Do You Want?");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Scheduled benifits");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Comprehensive Benifits");
            var s = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.Clear();

            if (s == "1")
            {
                //second print
                forQuote.gatherUserData();
            }
            else if (s == "2")
            {
                //comprehensive benifits
                //third print
                forQuote.gatherUserData();
            }
            else
            {
                //first else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please Try Again");
            }
        }
        else if (r == "2")
        {
            //trip canccelation
            //fourth print
            forQuote.gatherUserData();
        }
        else
        {
            //secondelse
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please Try Again");
            goto try3;
        }
    }
    else if (x == "3")
    {
        //immigration
        //fithprint
        forQuote.gatherUserData();
    }
    else if (x == "4")
    {
        //students...
        //sixthprint
        forQuote.gatherUserData();
    }
    else
    {
        //thirdelse
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please try Again");
        goto try2;
    }

}
```

This is only a small sample of this gross nest of `if`s. I have done a lot of research on cleaning this up and am having a hard time understanding/using the answers I found. 
The biggest problem I have had with refactoring has been that each following `if` is directly reliant on the `if` before it.

I also made a logic table of what input you need to reach each `if`. I'll drop it in here in case it's helpful:
[Excel table showing if paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZJ8b.png)

I would really appreciate some help, and an explanation of why your answer improves readability and efficiency would be excellent as well.

Comment: I know you are just starting so I wont yell at you too much for using `goto`, but **don't use goto**

Comment: The biggest tip I can give you in one sentence is to never use "goto". That statement can always be replaced with some sort of loop. Learn the "break" and "continue" keywords for loops. Also, always name classes and methods meaningfully. "loop.loops1" is useless and confusing.

Comment: @maccettura i have the goto's so that if an invalid input is used it takes you back to the start of the loop. i know its bad practice but i dont know a better way to do it.

Comment: You can also break some of these actions into void methods that handle each "menu".  This way your code isnt one giant mess, it would be modular and neat.

Comment: make try 1 try 2 as functions, have a dictionary with values against function and call those based on your values.

Comment: Don't use "goto"!   You can also use switch statements to make the logic a bit more clear.

Comment: @RaptorJesus if you _know_ it is bad practice then you should spend some more time on tutorials and take a step back to look at other ways to solve this.  Never do things that are bad practice cause you cant think of a better way.  Find the better way!  A path to go down is what I said earlier.  Name your variables and methods to be names that are more descriptive, break your logic up into pieces and reorganize.  Make each method responsible for one thing (like navigating one menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
bool loop = true;

while(loop)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Question");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Ans1");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Ans2");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
    string resp = Console.ReadLine();

    switch(resp)
    {
        case "1":
        Console.WriteLine("Ans1 chosen");
        break;
        case "2":
        SomeQuestion();
        break;
        case "3":
        loop = false;
        break;
        default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please try Again");
        break;        
    }
}

void SomeQuestion()
{
    bool loop = true;

    while(loop)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Question secon level");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Ans3");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Ans4");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
        string resp = Console.ReadLine();

        switch(resp)
        {
            case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("Ans1 chosen");
            break;
            case "2":
            break;
            case "3":
            loop = false;
            break;
            default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please try Again");
            break;        
        }
    }    
}
```

This is very simple, only one question but shows idea.

- Instead goto loop with condition.
- Instead if one switch which make code more readable.

Comment: wouldn't this just lead to a bunch of nested switches? is that worse or better than nested ifs?

or would i have case"2" break out of this while into another while that handles the logic of the subsequent chunk of ifs?

Comment: @RaptorJesus unfortunately with Console applications you will run into a lot of nested-ness.  Console applications are poor UI's for lots of user interactivity.  The post important thing to do is get rid of your `goto`'s entirely.  If you break things into separate methods that handle each menu then this wont be a mess, it will be clean

Comment: I think switches are more readable than ifs :-) I improve my exaple with second level

Comment: And in this way code is more readable. As say @maccettura  never use goto.

Comment: @RaptorJesus example improved, in this way you always has one level of switch

Comment: @BWA thank you, i get what your saying a lot more now. so in short break each chunk of if logic into a separate method with a while to handle the logic and get rid of the goto.

Comment: @RaptorJesus exactly, this  way code is more readable and easier to maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down some immediate problems first.

**The goto statement (bad):**

This statement is confusing because it doesn't go with the flow of execution. It basically says "Go to this arbitrary point in code that you have to find". Now multiply this by 3 or 4, and you have a maze with a bunch of teleport spots. You'll get lost extremely fast.

Here is an example of how to fix this:

```
if(condition)
{
    try2:

    // do stuff

    if(condition2)
    {
        // Do more stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Report error
        goto try2;
    }

}

// Replace with:

while(condition)
{
    // do stuff

    if(condition2)
    {
        // Do more stuff
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Report error
        continue; // Goes to the top of the loop
    }
}
```

This example isn't perfect and technically you don't need the "continue", but I wanted to explain its use.

**Naming Conventions:**

Every class name, variable name, method name, etc needs a descriptive identifier. "loop" tells me nothing. Be as descriptive as possible with naming. And if there is still some ambiguity left after doing so, **use comments to clear it up** in the definition.

**Nested Loops:**

Okay, this one is the overall design of your program. Unfortunately, console applications that ask a bunch of dependent questions are going to be messy.

Why?

Because this type of logic is handled much better by User Interface frameworks such as WPF. For example, a lot of your logic can be handled in button handlers and control properties.

However, **you can still improve your code**. But, it would require a very object-oriented design. I would choose a **state pattern** to start with.

State Pattern Resource: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/state-design-pattern-c-sharp

This, however, is **advanced** and not easy to understand if you haven't had a lot of experience with classes, methods, object, properties, handlers, etc. And, it doesn't even decrease your workload. In fact, it increases for the sake of readability and testability, both of which you might not even need if this is proof-of-concept or practice.

Therefore, my suggestion is to take your knowledge one step at a time. Developing the most robust solution is good, but not if your just starting. Pick up each piece one at a time until your experienced enough to put them all together.

Comment: this is a really good answer! thank you ill look into all this stuff. and i agree console application isn't the best for this project, after all in recreating a web application. so im trying to code stuff that is normally handled in the form of a button or drop down menu. but i don't have the skills or experience to make this as a web app.

Comment: @RaptorJesus making web apps are arguably easier than trying to write this in a console application.  Look into ASP.NET MVC & Bootstrap.  Lots of boilerplate and scaffolding that handle a lot of the work for you.

Comment: Not only that, but console application code won't port into a web app. You'll be rewriting the vast majority of it anyway. Might be better if you just try it on the platform you want. If you don't like the finished product, go learn, come back, do it again. I'm working on my 4th iteration of a library, and it hasn't even been released :)